# Microservices - should there be multiple instances of the same service?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I've been doing some research on microservices, and one question I've had that is not well addressed is whether there should be multiple instances of a microservice, and if so, how to deal with this?

Suppose I have a  microservices called filewatcher which fetching file from some shared drive here from FEED folder and create a record in table and send the payload message to kafka.

Here if multiple instance of filewatcher service running on different server (logical or physical server) and fetching file from same location than it will create the duplicate records.

Here I have already implemented validation from db side . But I am looking for some architectural solution. What is why filewatcher service read duplicate file from FEED folder.

I think @Transactional from spring boot that will resolve the transaction issue. It is not resolving the duplicate file upload issue.

How to handle this scenario?

Comment: Cool Question! I think this is good content for Stack Overflow. It addresses a common architectural problem.

Comment: This Question should not be closed as Opinion Based! This is a real-world Architecture problem that has definite clearly-defined solutions that relate directly to programming! Mods, please open this question back up!

Comment: I disagree.  As my answer clearly states, there are NO clearly defined solutions to the general problem.  And not even for the particular example posed by the OP.  (Or more precisely, there are many *possible* solutions ... none of which is either universally applicable, or more "correct" than others.)  Therefore answers are inevitably going to be opinion based.  The other alternative would be to close the question as Too Broad ... based on similar reasoning.

Comment: I think you could ask a more focussed question based on exactly what you are expecting @Transactional to do for you, including a sample of code.

Comment: No, it is not related to @Transactional,  It is related to architectural question, I think some issue application architecture for that I am looking some help here.

Comment: First of all, why multiple instances will create the problem here? If we are using the shared database/shared drive folder, then it's an anti-pattern of microservices. So there will be only one microservice(Firewatcher) that interacts with the shared drive, if any other microservice wants to get/post/delete data of the shared drive, then it should be through the only one microservice(Firewatcher) which actually does the operation on a shared drive.

Comment: Also, you have not mentioned that it is a stateless or stateful operation. If you deploy your service on k8s and replica of 3 and hit the endpoint, you will see only one pod gets the request and not all.But if it's background /cron type job then only it will run on all replica.

Comment: @Vaibs This not cloud base application nor exposing or consuming REST API. this a microservice reading files from the folder called FEED and details of file putting on KAFKA. And why multiple instance is running because its overloaded application works for multiple region, yes you can consider its is background job running as microservice .

Comment: okay got it. Spring already provided the plugin for this. Use spring shedlock plugin in this. refer https://www.baeldung.com/shedlock-spring.. Also, you can implement same type of implementation on your own if you dont want to use the library.

Comment: Voting to reopen, this isn't opinion based. The ability to have multiple instances of the same microservice and scale them all independantly is one of the fundamental benefits of the architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general question:

> Microservices - should there be multiple instances of the same service?

It depends why you are considering using them, and what the alternatives are.  For example, you could have multiple instances for redundancy, or because a single instance on a single machine doesn't have the capacity.  Or you could run multiple instances because the service and/or service stack is single threaded.

But running multiple instances of a microservice could breaks things if the service is not designed with this in mind.  Obviously, in that case you shouldn't do it.

Note: If microservice is (truly) stateless, then replicating it is less likely to break things from a "functional" perspective.  But this is hardly a useful observation, since there can still be ways that it *could* break things "operationally"; e.g. due to consuming resources ...

In short, you need to understand the context to decide whether you *should* or *should not* replicate a service.

---

An example:

> Here if multiple instance of filewatcher service running on different server (logical or physical server) and fetching file from same location than it will create the duplicate records.

That could be a scenario where you *don't* run multiple instances because it breaks things.  (What would you be achieving with multiple file watchers watching the same location?)

Alternatively you could implement the file watcher instances to de-dup the records as they put them into the database (assuming that you are using a database).  Or you could deal with the duplicate records later.

Either approach *could* be correct.  It depends on the context.

---

Bottom line:  I cannot think of any *general* architectural principles, techniques or advice, apart from the obvious advice that you need to understand the context, and decide what to do based on that.

Note: [There are no Best Practices](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164)

Answer (score 6):

**HIGH LEVEL**

I like your question, and I hope that my 2 cents is helpful.
You can absolutely have more than one **instance** of the microservice running at the same time, BUT they should not be logically separate. They must operate as one logical instance. Hence, the individual microservice that you are trying to scale should be built **stateless**, where all microservice stateful data is persisted across a shared database fabric. No internal states should be preserved on individual microservice instances if you intend to run multiple instances.

There are a few reasons that you may want to have a single microservice distributed across multiple instances.

1. Reliability comes to mind. In order to get the golden 99.99999% availability, you'll need to have multiple instances of the microservice running in case one instance crashes.
2. Scalability also plays a role here. With more than one instance of the microservice running, you can vertically scale your request capacity
3. In big data systems, it may be necessary to co-locate a microservice in separate physically distant areas to reduce latency.

**DATABASE SYNCHRONIZATION**

Therefore, the question is primarily: How do we ensure that microservice instances do not walk over each other when acting on shared data? The answer is that you must synchronize the database interactions and interactions with external systems.

Synchronizing database interactions in microservices can be done with Spring Boot's JDBC libraries. The `@Transactional` annotation with a `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` lock on the repository lookup can be used to ensure that only one instance of a microservice can create the database table entry. To read more on Transactionals and propagation methods, check out https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation. To understand more about Locking databases, read up on JDBC locking here : https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pessimistic-locking. Overall, you will need to take into consideration a database-layer strategy for synchronization between microservice instances.

If you need run a synchronized job on an EXTERNAL entity, I recommend the Quartz-Scheduler, which can use database transactions to synchronize a job. Be sure to utilize the `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` annotation. See http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

**LEADER ELECTION**

It is possible to create a leader election algorithm to synchronize microservice instances. In Leader Election, one microservice is "elected" by a shared algorithm to direct all other microservice instances. Thus, the leader instance could direct a subordinate instance to perform a critical region task. However, you need to be careful of making your leader instance a bottleneck for the system if you choose this pattern. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/leader-election

Comment: thanks for solution shared . Here I am using @Transactional to maintain the transaction consistency. I am looking for some architectural solution. Thanks

Comment: Another way of running multiple copies of a micro service, which removes (some) shared data and so makes life simpler is sharding. This is only possible if there's some way of distributing the work without communication, e.g. file names are generated randomly and each file watcher instance looks for a different prefix.